# How do I grab only the latest Invoice Number

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have Invoice Numbers that are stored as nvarchar(25).

Their Format is ‘####AA’
Where #### is the Invoice Number and AA is the Version Number (partial Order Shipping)
I cannot change the format.

I created two Scalar Functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnNumbersFromStr](@str varchar(8000))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@str)> 0
  SET @str = REPLACE(@str, SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @str), 1), '')
  RETURN CAST(@str AS INT)
END
```

And it’s brother:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnStringFromNum](@str varchar(25))
RETURNS varchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
  WHILE PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%',@str)> 0
  SET @str = REPLACE(@str, SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', @str), 1), '')
  RETURN @str
END
```

I am stalled with this script:

```
SELECT
strInvoiceNo,
    dbo.fnNumbersFromStr(strInvoiceNo) AS [InvoiceNumber],
    dbo.fnStringFromNum(strInvoiceNo) AS [InvoiceString]
FROM @TempTable
```

Which when runs returns:

```
strInvoiceNo    InvoiceNumber    InvoiceString

1000A           1000             A

1000B           1000             B

1000C           1000             C

1001A           1001             A

1001B           1001             B

1002AA          1002             AA

1002AB          1002             AB

1003A           1003             A

1004A           1004             A
```

I just can’t figure out the next step from here. I am stuck.

I would like the select to only return the latest Invoice Versions:

1000C
1001B
1002AB
1003A
1004A

Sql, Lamda or Linq will work fine for me.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you have a lot of rows, you might want to consider using inline table valued function instead of a scalar one, since then you can return both of the values with one operation, assuming it's always number + code -- but that is, slightly more difficult to code anyhow :)

Comment: You could make your life easier by splitting to two columns `invoiceNum` and `invoicePostfix` or something. It will also allow you to make a better query which will perform faster. Such as order by num desc, then by postfix desc, take first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  InvoiceNumber + MAX(InvoiceString) As strInvoiceNo    
FROM
(
   SELECT
       dbo.fnNumbersFromStr(strInvoiceNo) AS [InvoiceNumber],
       dbo.fnStringFromNum(strInvoiceNo) AS [InvoiceString]
   FROM @TempTable
) As tbl
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
```

Comment: This worked great @Magnus! However, I did need to change my first Function to return varchar rather than cast it as an int.

Comment: Just a reminder that this won't actually work, but does get the answer mostly correct.  The InvoiceString portion will fail once the invoice revision hits Z, as the next revision AA isn't greater than Z when getting the MAX of them.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need any UDF for this, a simple windowing function query should return what you looking for.

```
WITH x AS
(
 Select *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceNumber ORDER BY strInvoiceNo DESC) rn 
 FROM TableName
)
SELECT strInvoiceNo, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceString 
FROM X 
WHERE rn = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT strInvoiceNo, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceString 
FROM 
(
 Select *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceNumber ORDER BY strInvoiceNo DESC) rn 
 FROM TableName
)x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I do like your implementation @M.Ali, however having a function is not a huge problem for me. The number of records I need to sort through will most likely be less than 200 at a time. I am only looking at Open Invoices not every invoice past and present.

Answer (score 1):

Here is it in LINQ (Assuming fnStringFromNum returns a string padded on the left with spaces):

```
dbContext.YOURTABLE
  .GroupBy(x=>UDFFunctions.fnNumbersFromStr(x.AccountNumber))
  .Select(x=>x.OrderByDescending(y=>UDFFunctions.fnStringFromNum(y.AccountNumber).FirstOrDefault())
```

SQL (using current fnStringFromNum):

```
SELECT
  InvoiceNumber + LTRIM(MAX(RIGHT(SPACE(20)+InvoiceString,20))) As strInvoiceNo    
FROM
(
   SELECT
       dbo.fnNumbersFromStr(strInvoiceNo) AS [InvoiceNumber],
       dbo.fnStringFromNum(strInvoiceNo) AS [InvoiceString]
   FROM @TempTable
) As tbl
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Robert. The only problem I see is the AccountNumber field (representative in my problem)  is not fixed as only four digits long. Sorry, I failed to mention that in the original post. This answer is short and sweet however, and would probably work for a while.

Comment: Updated the answer using your `fnNumbersFromStr` function, but you will need to map it so you can use it like above.  One question I would ask is.. Is `AB` a version after `B` or is it a sub-version of `A` and then falls between `A` and `B`?

Comment: You might just want to create a couple computed columns on your invoice table to call your UDFs on the AccountNumber.  Might simplify things for you in the future.  LIke: `ALTER TABLE dbo.Invoices ADD InvoiceNumber AS dbo.fnNumbersFromStr(AccountNumber); ALTER TABLE dbo.Invoices ADD InvoiceRevision AS dbo.fnStringFromNum(AccountNumber)`

Comment: The next version after version 'Z' would be 'AA', then next would be 'AB' then next 'AC' and so on... as an aside, I thought calling a UDF from Linq (EntityFramework 6 with Model-First) was not working? For me the actual table is read-only plus the db is third party.

Comment: Then you will need to right pad your string before sorting or `AA` will fall between `A` and `B`.  UDF from Linq works fine in EF 6.  We use database first though, so I'm not sure if that is an issue. You can pad like this: `RIGHT(SPACE(20)+somefield,20)`  Change 20 to whatever you feel is the most digits you'll ever get.

Comment: Thank you for the "Heads-Up" on the Sorting Issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the most efficient, but this will work:

```
select strInvoiceNo
from @TempTable T
where InvoiceString = (select max(invoicestring) from temp1 where invoicenumber = T.invoicenumber)
order by 1
```

Edit:  Sorry....disregard.  This will work off of your full result table but may not be what you actually need.  Apologies.