# How can I sort version numbers such as ‘A’, ‘B’, ‘AA’, ‘AB’ and ‘AAA’?

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

In reference to this question: [How do I grab only the latest Invoice Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353249/)

I accepted an answer that uses the MAX function but Robert McKee pointed out that will result in sorted values such as:

```
‘A’
‘AA’
‘AAA’
‘AB’
‘B’
```

When what I need is:

```
‘A’
‘B’
‘AA’
‘AB’
‘AAA’
```

I am trying to find a way to find the latest Version of an Invoice. The accepted answer from the referenced question will work up to a point. And it did satisfy my question... But now a new problem deserves its own question and not for me to go back and modify my original question. So…

The only thing I have to work with is the Invoice Number itself.
The Invoice number has a format of  #####XXX, where ##### is the actual Invoice Number and the XXX is the version number. XXX can be anywhere from ‘A’ to ‘ZZZ’.

Here is my attempt to find a plausible work around (a sql test case):

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (MyNumber int, MyString varchar(15));

INSERT @TempTable
VALUES (100, 'A'), (100, 'AAZ'), (100, 'B'), (100, 'AZ'), (100, 'C'), (100, 'Z'), (100, 'AA'), (100, 'AB');

SELECT TOP 1
RTRIM(CAST(MyNumber AS NVARCHAR(15)) + MyString) AS InvoiceNumber
FROM @TempTable
ORDER BY RIGHT(LEFT(MyString + SPACE(2), 3), 1) DESC, RIGHT(LEFT(MyString + SPACE(2), 2), 1) DESC, LEFT(MyString, 1) DESC;
```

Would anyone care to provide a better answer or point me in the right direction to clean mine up?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ORDER BY LEN(myValue),myValue
```

this will order the 1-character, then the 2-character, etc...

Comment: Plain and simple, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this meets your definition of "better" or "cleaned up":

`ORDER BY LEFT(MyString,1),SUBSTRING(MyString,2,1),SUBSTRING(MyString,3,1)`